# Call Method in framework

Tags: ios, swift, methods, frameworks

I have a custom swift framework that I am trying to access via my project.

The method in my framework is

```
public func test(url:String, callType:String){  
}
```

and I am trying to access it from my main project with 
    import FrameworkName

```
FrameworkName.FrameworkSwiftClass.test()
```

The problem is that it looks like it is looking for

```
FrameworkName.FrameworkSwiftClass.test(FrameworkSwiftClass)
```

Why is XCode telling me extra argument when I try

```
FrameworkName.FrameworkSwiftClass.test(url:"url", callType:"type")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the method as if it was a static method but it's not, you have to instantiate your class first:

```
let framework = FrameworkName.FrameworkSwiftClass()
framework.test(url:"url", callType:"type")
```